# Como obtener la lista de categorias de posts sin las categorias de custom post type? - php/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, blog

Estoy creando un Blog en wordpress.

Tengo una lista de categorias:
Tecnologia,
Arte,
Moda,
Hogar,
Vida,
Educacion,
Negocios,
Religion,
Diseño y hogar,
Marketing,

En la cuales algunas de estas categorias las estoy usando sólo en Custom Post Type (Tecnologia, Arte, Moda) y otras sólo en Posts Normales (Hogar, Vida, Educacion, Negocios, Religion, Diseño y hogar, Marketing).

Ahora necesito obtener la lista de categorías que sólo se están usando en posts normales para mostrarlos en mi blog.
Intenté hacer lo siguiente pero me devuelve todas las categorias incluidas las de CPT.

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category):
    <li class="cat-name"> <?phpp echo $category->name ?></li>
endforeach;
```

Solo necesito mostrar las categorias:
Hogar, Vida, Educacion, Negocios, Religion, Diseño y hogar, Marketing
Y excluir las que se están usando en CPT.